# How to add images as an option in a combo box in Java FX

Tags: java, javafx

I tried adding images to a combo box to show them as options but once i select the images they turn white when the dropdown opens again to select them they turn white.

```
ImageView img1 = new ImageView(getClass().getResource("item1.png").toExternalForm());
ImageView img2 = new ImageView(getClass().getResource("item2.jpg").toExternalForm());
ImageView img3 = new ImageView(getClass().getResource("item3.jpg").toExternalForm());
img1.setFitHeight(60);
img1.setFitWidth(60);
img1.setPreserveRatio(true);
img2.setFitHeight(60);
img2.setFitWidth(60);
img2.setPreserveRatio(true);
img3.setFitHeight(60);
img3.setFitWidth(60);
img3.setPreserveRatio(true);
combobox.getItems().addAll(img1,img2,img3);
```

the choices work only once and they turn white when i try to select them again.

Comment: What choices? Also, what is `combobox`?

Comment: ComboBox in java fx

Comment: don't add nodes (here: imageView) as data, never ever and particularly not for combos. Instead, add images as data and implement a custom ListCell that has an ImageView as its graphic and set its image to the given item in updateItem .. and read a basic fx tutorial _now_!

Comment: okay i will,i think i got in over my head thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting the elements properly. You need to utilise the setCellFactory() method of the combobox in order for list items to be generated correctly as the Items are expected to be a list of relevant data, not Nodes. The ListCell object can then have setGraphic(ImageView) called upon itw, and updates that element of the list to the specified image.

Here is some example code from an old project of mine, which is actually designed for a ListView but will work exactly the same as the ComboBox:

```
pieceData = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Boot", "Car", "Dog", "Hat", "Iron",
                                                  "Ship", "Thimble", "Wheelbarrow");
pieceSelection.setItems(pieceData);

pieceSelection.setCellFactory(e -> new ListCell<String>() {
    private ImageView view = new ImageView();
    @Override
    public void updateItem(String name, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(name, empty);
        if(empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
        }
        else {
            view.setImage(new Image("whatever the filepath to your image is"));
            // Add other set up for ImageView dimensions etc
            setGraphic(view);
        }
    }
});
```

Bear in mind that this only displayed the images, because the method setText(String) is required to be called in order to have any text displayed.

Also as kleopatra stated, you should read a basic JavaFX tutorial since this type of thing is well documented and relatively simple.

Comment: good answer :) Just a slight misunderstanding: _Items are expected to be a list of Strings_ - not necessarily, they can be any type (except Nodes - which even is possible for all virtualized controls except combo) as long as the cell implementation can handle it. So one might consider loading the images up front and have them as data (vs. reloading them each time updateItem is called, which is very frequent)

Comment: Actually creating images on every `updateItem` call like this can be a bad idea. If those images are big (using `fitWidth`/`fitHeight`) and or there are enough of them this can really slow down the perfomance when scrolling. It may be better to create a cache for those images... (the general code would remain the same, you'd just use more complicated code to get the instance of `Image` to use)

Comment: Completely agree, the code for this was using 100x100 images, but it would certainly be a better idea to cache the Images rather than constantly create new Objects